# Application Automation with AutoHotkey while Using the Computer

Tags: scripting, autohotkey, hotkeys

It is possible to create an **AutoHotkey** script that will allow me to automate a task of an application, such refreshing of tabs on a web browser, which in the other side is I am using the computer? For example, creating an *.ahk* script that will allow me to manually post a blog with the primary web browser, while on the secondary browser is automatically refreshing their two tabs every after 10 seconds.

- If it's possible, would you please give me a little bit of tips.
- And if it's not, then give me a little bit of alternatives.

Thank you!

Comment: Yes Possible, but this section "which in the other side is I am using the computer where do I use this .ahk script?" is not clear to me. You run the script on the machine where you want the automatic Refresh to take place.

Comment: @RobertIlbrink No.. For example, I'm blogging with my web browser, while in the other web browser is automatically refreshing their two tabs every after 10 seconds.

Comment: Wow, every 10 seconds.... Which browser do you use? Are they BOTH the same browser. And what is the reason to refresh every 10 seconds when you are focused on your primary browser? Refreshing 1 tab which is open and visible on a second screen makes sense, but two tabs? Normally you would use the WindowsTitle to distinguish between the two browsers/tabs and you could use ControlSend to send e.g. F5 (in the background) to the second Browser, whilst working in the first browser.

Comment: @RobertIlbrink :) Actually, I am asking if it's possible with **AutoHotkey**.. I want to create an *.ahk* script that will automate the refreshing of two tabs in the secondary web browser while I'm doing a different kind of task in the primary browser. It is possible? *(I think, it's not.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What problems are you running into? By using ControlSend, you can send commands to a background window without activating it. Since I did not want to refresh, I send {F6} and {Shift}{F6}, so I can see activity. This loop toggles happily between two tabs in Chrome, while I am using another application...

```
Loop
{
ControlSend, , {F6}, Macro Creator v3.7.1
Sleep, 100
ControlSend, , +{F6}, Macro Creator v3.7.1
Sleep, 100
ControlSend, , ^{PgDn}, Macro Creator v3.7.1 ; Jump to next tab with script - Desktop Automation in the title
Sleep, 100
ControlSend, , {F6}, script - Desktop Automation
Sleep, 100
ControlSend, , +{F6}, script - Desktop Automation
Sleep, 100
ControlSend, , ^{PgUp}, script - Desktop Automation ; Jump to Previous tab with Macro Creator v3.7.1 in the title
Sleep, 100
}
Return
```

Comment: But `ControlSend` doesn't working if I'm in the other tab or working with other web browser..

Comment: Servant, Did you use the right "Title" strings for ControlSend and did you set the SetTitleMatchMode, 2? You can't control other Chrome tabs when you are working in the SAME browser, but when you open a second one, the first browser toggles between tab1 and tab2, even when working in the second browser. Alternatively, you could look at using IE, since IE can be controlled through objects which is way more reliable.

Comment: Yes, it's working on an automated web browser that has 2 specific tabs even I open a second browser.. Do you think it will also work when I open a 3D application such video game? Is there a possible way to control a tab of a browser even if I'm at the other tab in the same browser? *(Note: I tested `ControlSend` by using **IE**, there're all the same.)*

Comment: When using IE, I suggest you look at using com in AutoHotKey. This will give better control than using controlsend. Have a look at his: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lr4AVCS6y0g and http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/64563-basic-ahk-l-com-tutorial-for-webpages/ . Even though some games will block the AutoHotKey sendinput data, the AutoHotKey script should continue to work it's magic on your browser. When using ControlSend, you can't use the same browser to do other work as well as this would interfere with the tabs that are switched back and forth.